# How to make SQL request COUNT DISTINCT with conditions?

Tags: sql, count, db2, case, distinct

I have table INTERACTIONS that contains

- datetime,
- customer ID,
- customer segment (group 'A' or group 'B'),
- customer response.

Table sample:

> ```
> datetime       | CustomerID | Segment | Response
> ---------------+------------+---------+---------
> 20181126000001 | 1          | A       | Accept  
> 20181126000005 | 1          | A       | Ignore  
> 20181126000010 | 2          | B       | Ignore  
> 20181126000015 | 3          | A       | Accept
> ```

My task is to make request that gets distinct customers count with conditions:

1. count customers that belongs to segment 'A';
2. if there is no customers from segment 'A' then count all customers.

So in pseudocode I want to do something like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN 
        (select count distinct CustomerID from INTERACTIONS where Segment = 'A') = 0 
    THEN 
        (select count distinct CustomerID from INTERACTIONS)
    ELSE
        (select count distinct CustomerID from INTERACTIONS where Segment = 'A')
END
```

Expected result - single value. In this sample result = 2.

Can you help to write the full request to DB?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Added sample table data and the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a *derived table* (the subquery) where you use a `case` expression to do *conditional aggregation* to count A segment customers, and to count all customers.

```
select case when acnt > 0 then acnt else allcnt end
from
(
    select count(distinct case when segment = 'A' then CustomerID end) acnt,
           count(distinct CustomerID) allcnt
    from INTERACTIONS
) dt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
select 
CASE
    WHEN count(distinct case when Segment = 'A' then CustomerID end)=0 THEN count(distinct CustomerID)
    ELSE
        count(distinct case when Segment = 'A' then CustomerID end)
from INTERACTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sub query (avoid twice calculation)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN T.customer_a > 0 THEN customer_a ELSE customer_all FROM
(
   SELECT 
       (SELECT count(distinct customer_id) FROM INTERACTIONS WHERE segment = 'A') AS customer_a,        
       (SELECT count(distinct customer_id) FROM INTERACTIONS) AS customer_all   )
) AS T
```